# Remove all but valid characters

Tags: php, regex

Valid characters include the alphabet (abcd..), numbers (0123456789), spaces, ' and ".

I need to strip any other characters than these from a string in PHP.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 "\']/', '', $str);
```

Here the character class `[^a-z0-9 "']` will match any character except the listed ones (note the inverting `^` at the begin of the character class) that are then replaced by an empty string.

Comment: Don't you need the regex to be: `/[^a-z0-9 "\']/g` to match ALL occurrences of these characters? (as opposed to only the first one)

Comment: RazorStorm, you're mixing up preg_replace with preg_match and preg_match_all. See:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php --
"The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit)."

Comment: Oh I see, haha been doing too much perl lately. :P

Answer (score 2):

[Gumbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504879/remove-all-but-valid-characters/3504885#3504885) is correct for your given specification. But if your "specification" is only "symbolic", what you eventually need might be like the following:

```
$str = preg_replace('{ [^ \w \s \' " ] }x', '', $str );
```

`[^   ]`: negated character class (all **except** these inside)

`\w`: alphanumeric (letters and digits)

`\s`: white space

`\'`: '